# Input type more than one word next print in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I create a dictionary file with input data by retrieving data from the database json and it went well. but it was only one word , when I was trying to use two words was not running only one word is read.

This database json

```
[{"id":"1","kingdom":"Metazoa ","phylum":"Arthropoda ","class":"Insecta ","order":"Hemiptera ","family":"Belostomatidae ","genus":"Abedus"},
{"id":"2","kingdom":"Viridiplantae ","phylum":"Streptophyta ","class":"unclassified_Streptophyta ","order":"Pinales ","family":"Pinaceae ","genus":"Abies"}]
```

This my script json

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import urllib2
import simplejson as json
import optparse

response = urllib2.urlopen("http://localhost/csv/taxo.json")
database = json.load(response)

parser = optparse.OptionParser(usage="usage: %prog [options] genus_name",
                   version="%prog v.1.0")

parser.add_option("-g",
          action="store",
          default=False,
          help="input genus taxonomy")

options, args = parser.parse_args()

if options.g == 0:
 parser.error("wrong option of arguments")

for taxonomy in database:
 if taxonomy["genus"] == options.g:
  print "Result find taxonomy"
  print "Kingdom :", taxonomy['kingdom'],
  print "phylum :", taxonomy['phylum'],
  print "class :", taxonomy['class'],
  print "order :", taxonomy['order'],
  print "family :", taxonomy['family'],
  print "genus :", taxonomy['genus']
  break
else:
 print ("No found genus on taxanomy")
```

Example

```
myscript.py -g Abedus,Abies
```

the results of only one data showing "Abedus", "Abies" not showing

Comment: thanks @cricket_007 not only database.json I call on the server , no HTML tags

Comment: You are breaking out of your for-loop after the first iteration. Try removing the `break`

Comment: thansk @juanpa.arrivillaga I remove the `break` but still the same, I used the break to take one of the same data

Comment: @dwiyanto Please print `response` output. I suspect something wring with your JSON

Comment: @cricket_007, where `<br>`??

Comment: @Samuel , this result output print using one word,`Result find taxonomy
Kingdom : Viridiplantae  phylum : Streptophyta  class : unclassified_Streptophyta  order : Pinales  family : Pinaceae  genus : Abies`

Comment: @cricket_007, I use `<br >` to create the script on this question and it is only a sample without `<br >` , but on all database pure json

Comment: @dwiyanto Can you please check your original JSON ( from http://localhost/csv/taxo.json) VS [JSON Validator](http://jsonlint.com/) to be sure your JSON is valid